# [Shape click event][Active shape index] How to retrieve the index of a drawn shape, on which user clicked on, using an event?

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

I need to draw rectangles using the ‘drawrect’ button on a heatmap and obtain the index of the active shape when it is clicked on.

Currently, the plotly_click event does not trigger when I click on the shape outline, and the plotly_relayout event only triggers when the shape is dragged, resized, or erased.

A simple example is available here [codepenExample](https://codepen.io/YaellePihan/pen/bGxqeam) or here:

**HTML:**

```
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="graph"></div>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
var shapes = [
  {
    editable: true,
    label: { text: "" },
    xref: "x",
    yref: "y",
    layer: "above",
    opacity: 1,
    line: { color: "white", width: 5, dash: "solid" },
    fillcolor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
    fillrule: "evenodd",
    type: "rect",
    x0: 0.5,
    y0: 0,
    x1: 0.75,
    y1: 1.5
  }
];

var fig = {
  data: [
    {
      z: [
        [1, 20, 30],
        [20, 1, 60],
        [30, 60, 1]
      ],
      type: "heatmap"
    }
  ],
  layout: {
    title: "Heatmap with drawn rectangles",
    shapes: shapes,
    dragmode: "drawrect",
    clickmode: "event+select"
  },
  config: {
    displayModeBar: true,
    modeBarButtons: [[], ["zoom2d", "drawrect", "eraseshape", "autoScale2d"]]
  }
};

var gd = document.getElementById("graph");

Plotly.plot(gd, fig);

gd.on("plotly_click", function (d) {
  alert("plotly click");
  console.log(d);
});

gd.on("plotly_relayouting", function (d) {
  alert("plotly relayouting");
  console.log(d);
});

// gd.on("plotly_relayout", function(d) {
//   alert("plotly relayout")
//   console.log(d)
// })

// gd.on("plotly_selected", function(d) {
//   alert("plotly selected")
//   console.log(d);
// });

// gd.on("plotly_selecting", function(d) {
//   alert("plotly selecting")
//   console.log(d);
// });
```

I have looked into the draw.js file of the plotly.js source code ([draw.js](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/components/shapes/draw.js)) and found the function that is automatically triggered when a shape is clicked on to change its style and make it draggable, resizable, or erasable (line 189):

`path.node().addEventListener('click', function() { return activateShape(gd, path); });`

Therefore, I believe there should be a way to add actions to this ‘click’ event and obtain its index as well.

I have also read about some dependencies with the dragmode and clickmode attributes’ values, but I am unable to proceed with them.

Thanks a lot for your help!
Yaya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked for the `function activateShape(gd, path)` it in the plotly library, and added console.log for all the arguments:

```
function activateShape(gd, path) {
  if (!couldHaveActiveShape(gd)) return;
  var element = path.node();
  var id = +element.getAttribute('data-index');
  if (id >= 0) {
    // deactivate if already active
    if (id === gd._fullLayout._activeShapeIndex) {
      deactivateShape(gd);
      return;
    }
    gd._fullLayout._activeShapeIndex = id;
    gd._fullLayout._deactivateShape = deactivateShape;
    draw(gd);
    console.log(gd, path, element, id);
  }
}
```

The `id` is the index of the shape.

Replacing the `console.log()` with the following:

```
gd.emit('plotly_relayout', {"shape": gd._fullLayout.shapes[id]});
```

Now you will have a `plotly_relayout` event fired with the active shape as an argument. To catch this event you can use something like the following code:

```
div.on('plotly_relayout', function (eventData) {
    console.log('plotly_relayout:');
    if (eventData.hasOwnProperty('shape')) {
        console.log(true);
        alert(eventData.shape.x0 + ', ' + eventData.shape.x1 + ', ' + eventData.shape.y0 + ', ' + eventData.shape.y1);
    } else {
        console.log(false);
    }
    console.log(eventData);
}
)
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but how can I use a modified version of this Plotly internal function (that would return the index/id of the shape selected/clicked on) in my code more concretly ?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi again, 
So, should I create a node js module which would basically be a copy of react-plotly.js package with this line "gd.emit('plotly_relayout', {"shape": gd._fullLayout.shapes[id]});" added ? 
Thanks

Comment: Yes, this modified version of `react-plotly.js` will fire a `plotly_relayout` event with `{ shape: [activeShapeID] }` as payload.